# TestNG Eclipse plugin does not appear to be installed after successfully installing

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, testng, testng-eclipse

```
1.) I am on a Mac running Eclipse Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a) Build id: 20180405-1200
2.) Go to Help -> Install New Software...
3.) Add TestNG http://beust.com/eclipse
4.) Select the TestNG Plugins.
5.) Go through the screens to install it.
6.) Restart Eclipse when requested.
7.) Go to Window -> Show View -> Other...
```

EXPECTED: TestNG would be listed.

RESULT: TestNG is no where to be seen as an option in any context menus. I cannot create TestNG files.

I have tried running Eclipse as Clean per this thread: [Why am I unable to show Ecplise-Plugin after successfully installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37804177/why-am-i-unable-to-show-ecplise-plugin-after-successfully-installed).

I have tried manually deleting the p[lugins in .p2 via this thread: [Eclipse: remove plugins that fail to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223763/eclipse-remove-plugins-that-fail-to-load)

I have used Oomph to fix what I did above using this thread: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1723920/#msg_1723920

Does anyone know why the TestNG plugin options are not showing up in my Eclipse install?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Marketplace, It will directly installed as Package for Eclipse. Help->Eclipse Marketplace

[image: Reference Screenshot]

Comment: I was hoping that would solve it. When I go there, it says "Installed".

Comment: Fine. Then you need to just install Maven Dependency for TestNG. If you are using Maven. Else you need to install testng jar in to project : http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/testng/testng/6.14.3/testng-6.14.3.jar

Comment: I tried doing the same with Eclipse 2019R06, Eclipse 2018-12, Oxygen etc versions, and all of them had the same problem, when at work. But my computer did not complain and installed perfectly. So, it is a proxy preventing it. When I disabled it, it is working perfectly. To figure this out, I need to waste so many hours. But it is my bad that, it has been mentioned in the troubleshooting guide though.